# Convert historical data in (date )type oracle to unix timestamp considering daylight saving

Tags: database, datetime, unix, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am able to convert date in unix timestamp. But I am facing an issue in converting historical data in database to correct unix timestamp. Since data saved in date format so there is no timezones available for those data. Is there any way I can determine whether any historical date is in cdt or cst.

Currently I am using one of the methods to convert date in timestamp.

```
create or replace function unix_time_from_date
      (
        in_date   in date
      --  in_src_tz in varchar2 default 'America/Chicago'
      )
    return integer
  as
    ut      integer       := 0;
    tz      varchar2(8)   := '';
    tz_date timestamp with time zone;
    tz_stmt varchar2(255);
    in_src_tz varchar2(255):='America/Chicago';
  begin
 tz_stmt := 'select systimestamp at time zone ''' || in_src_tz || ''' from dual';



    execute immediate tz_stmt into tz_date;
    select
      extract(timezone_abbr from tz_date)
    into tz
    from dual;



    -- Get the Unix timestamp
    select
      (new_time(in_date, tz, 'GMT') - to_date('01-JAN-1970', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) * (86400)
    into ut
    from dual;

    return ut;
end unix_time_from_date;
```

Taken from :http://jrfom.com/2015archive/2012/02/10/oracle-and-unix-timestamps-revisited/

Since objects stored have no timezone it will take sys timezone as cdt and gives difference of 1 hr for data in cst timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is extracting the time zone abbreviation for *today* and applying that to the supplied date, effectively assuming that all dates are in that zone. It will give the right result half the time - but only to half the values passed in. (In winter it will get the summer time wrong; in summer it will get the winter times wrong). If you used the region name instead of the abbreviation then it wouldn't do that. But then you can't use `new_time()`, which only recognises a few zones anyway, so you have to use `at time zone`.

With sample dates from the last six months (to cross the DST boundary; this is run in London but will work in Chicago too, and your function if assuming Chicago), you can see what your current function gives you:

```
with t (dt) as (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate), -level)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 6
)
select dt dt,
  unix_time_from_date(dt) unix_time_from_date
from t
order by dt;

DT                  UNIX_TIME_FROM_DATE
------------------- -------------------
2015-12-21 00:00:00          1450674000
2016-01-21 00:00:00          1453352400
2016-02-21 00:00:00          1456030800
2016-03-21 00:00:00          1458536400
2016-04-21 00:00:00          1461214800
2016-05-21 00:00:00          1463806800
```

You can tell Oracle which time zone region the date is supposed to represent. If you cast the date to a timestamp it essentially stays the same. If you cast it to a timestamp with tome zone then it assumes the server's time zone. You can then convert that to UTC with `at time zone`, and subtract 1970-01-01 from that to get the epoch number:

```
with t (dt) as (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate), -level)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 6
)
select dt dt,
  cast(dt as timestamp) ts,
  cast(dt as timestamp with time zone) tstz,
  cast(dt as timestamp with time zone) at time zone 'UTC' as utc,
  86400 * (cast(cast(dt as timestamp with time zone) at time zone 'UTC' as date)
    - date '1970-01-01') as epoch
from t
order by dt;

DT                  TS                  TSTZ                              UTC                           EPOCH
------------------- ------------------- --------------------------------- ----------------------- -----------
2015-12-21 00:00:00 2015-12-21 00:00:00 2015-12-21 00:00:00 Europe/London 2015-12-21 00:00:00 UTC  1450656000
2016-01-21 00:00:00 2016-01-21 00:00:00 2016-01-21 00:00:00 Europe/London 2016-01-21 00:00:00 UTC  1453334400
2016-02-21 00:00:00 2016-02-21 00:00:00 2016-02-21 00:00:00 Europe/London 2016-02-21 00:00:00 UTC  1456012800
2016-03-21 00:00:00 2016-03-21 00:00:00 2016-03-21 00:00:00 Europe/London 2016-03-21 00:00:00 UTC  1458518400
2016-04-21 00:00:00 2016-04-21 00:00:00 2016-04-21 00:00:00 Europe/London 2016-04-20 23:00:00 UTC  1461193200
2016-05-21 00:00:00 2016-05-21 00:00:00 2016-05-21 00:00:00 Europe/London 2016-05-20 23:00:00 UTC  1463785200
```

As an alternative way to get the UTC equivalent, still based on the server time zone, you can use [`sys_extract_utc`()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions186.htm):

```
with t (dt) as (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate), -level)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 6
)
select dt dt,
  cast(dt as timestamp) ts,
  cast(dt as timestamp with time zone) tstz,
  sys_extract_utc(cast(dt as timestamp)) as utc,
  86400 * (cast(sys_extract_utc(cast(dt as timestamp with time zone)) as date)
    - date '1970-01-01') as epoch
from t
order by dt;
```

Or if you don't want to use the server time zone but specify one instead, which is slightly more helpful for this demo anyway:

```
with t (dt) as (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate), -level)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 6
)
select dt dt,
  cast(dt as timestamp) ts,
  from_tz(cast(dt as timestamp), 'America/Chicago') tstz,
  from_tz(cast(dt as timestamp), 'America/Chicago') at time zone 'UTC' as utc,
  86400 * (cast(from_tz(cast(dt as timestamp), 'America/Chicago') at time zone 'UTC' as date)
    - date '1970-01-01') as epoch
from t
order by dt;

DT                  TS                  TSTZ                                UTC                           EPOCH
------------------- ------------------- ----------------------------------- ----------------------- -----------
2015-12-21 00:00:00 2015-12-21 00:00:00 2015-12-21 00:00:00 America/Chicago 2015-12-21 06:00:00 UTC  1450677600
2016-01-21 00:00:00 2016-01-21 00:00:00 2016-01-21 00:00:00 America/Chicago 2016-01-21 06:00:00 UTC  1453356000
2016-02-21 00:00:00 2016-02-21 00:00:00 2016-02-21 00:00:00 America/Chicago 2016-02-21 06:00:00 UTC  1456034400
2016-03-21 00:00:00 2016-03-21 00:00:00 2016-03-21 00:00:00 America/Chicago 2016-03-21 05:00:00 UTC  1458536400
2016-04-21 00:00:00 2016-04-21 00:00:00 2016-04-21 00:00:00 America/Chicago 2016-04-21 05:00:00 UTC  1461214800
2016-05-21 00:00:00 2016-05-21 00:00:00 2016-05-21 00:00:00 America/Chicago 2016-05-21 05:00:00 UTC  1463806800
```

And comparing that calculated epoch with your function:

```
with t (dt) as (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate), -level)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 6
)
select dt dt,
  unix_time_from_date(dt) unix_time_from_date,
  86400 * (cast(from_tz(cast(dt as timestamp), 'America/Chicago') at time zone 'UTC' as date)
    - date '1970-01-01') as epoch,
  unix_time_from_date(dt) -
    (  86400 * (cast(from_tz(cast(dt as timestamp), 'America/Chicago') at time zone 'UTC' as date)
    - date '1970-01-01')) as diff
from t
order by dt;

DT                  UNIX_TIME_FROM_DATE       EPOCH   DIFF
------------------- ------------------- ----------- ------
2015-12-21 00:00:00          1450674000  1450677600  -3600
2016-01-21 00:00:00          1453352400  1453356000  -3600
2016-02-21 00:00:00          1456030800  1456034400  -3600
2016-03-21 00:00:00          1458536400  1458536400      0
2016-04-21 00:00:00          1461214800  1461214800      0
2016-05-21 00:00:00          1463806800  1463806800      0
```

But you are still having to state - and thus *maybe* assume - what time zone the date originally represented. You're already doing that in your function so I don't think that is a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not able to cast at UTC before posting question. You solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here are the two functions I've made for this:

```
function toUnixEpoch(d in date) return number
is
begin
    return ROUND((cast(from_tz(cast(d as timestamp), 'Europe/Stockholm') at time zone 'UTC' as date) - date '1970-01-01') * 86400);
end;

function toDate(unixEpoch in number) return date
is
begin
    return cast(from_tz(timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'+unixEpoch/86400, 'UTC') at time zone 'Europe/Stockholm' as date);
end;
```

Put these in a package ("packagename" below) and,
set the time zone region to your own ("Europe/Stockholm" above).

Test with Alex's perfect SQL:

```
with t (d) as (
  select TRUNC(add_months(trunc(sysdate), -level))+8/24 from dual connect by level <= 6
)
select d as "Date",
  cast(d as timestamp) as "Timestamp",
  from_tz(cast(d as timestamp), 'Europe/Stockholm') as "Timestamp with time zone",
  from_tz(cast(d as timestamp), 'Europe/Stockholm') at time zone 'UTC' as "UTC",
  packagename.toUnixEpoch(d) as "Unix Epoch",
  packagename.toDate(wfg.toUnixEpoch(d)) as "Back to Date"
from t
order by 1
```

As you can see, "Date" and "Back to Date" is supposed to be the same, regardless of daylight savings.